# validate input is not empty on submit

Tags: javascript, php, forms, validation

The following echo statement creates an empty textbox and a submit button using php.

```
    echo"<td><form id=\"edit\" name=\"edit\" method=\"post\" action=\"../assets/modules/coursemanager/process.cm.php\" onsubmit=\"return check_edit();\">
    <input type=\"text\" size=\"3\" id=\"edit_places\" name=\"edit_places\" value=\"\" />
    <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"sid\" value=\"".$sid."\" />
    <input type=\"submit\" name=\"Submit\" value=\"edit places\" /></form></td>";
```

This is the validation JavaScript I am using, but the above form is ignoring it.

```
  function check_edit(){
      var notempty=document.forms["edit"]["edit_places"].value;
        if(notempty==null || notempty==""){
           alert("Please enter the new number of available places and try again");
           return false;
      }else{    
           return true;
      }
  }
```

I would be very grateful if someone could show me my error.

Comment: Not sure if this is your problem but `notempty==nul || notempty==""` should be `notempty==null || notempty==""`.  Also because of how Javascript works, a simpler way of saying that is `if(!notempty)`, which will handle `null` and `""` but also `undefined` `false` and `0`.  If you only want to check `null`/`""`, you should use `===` instead of just `==`.

Comment: `null` is misspelled on the third line

Comment: Ah yes, thank you for that Josh. I have corrected that in the post :)

Answer (score 1):

You can check the length of the input.

```
value = document.forms["edit"]["edit_places"].value.replace(/\s+/g, '')

if (value.length > 0) {
  return true;
} else {
  alert("Please enter the new number of available places and try again");
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Knouroozi. I have resolved it as follows:

Answer (score 0):

I used an else statement in the processing script which does the trick and dispensed with the check_edit function.

```
    if($_POST['edit_places']!== ''){
    $id=$_POST['sid'];
    $z=$_POST['edit_places'];
    $sql = "UPDATE xtra_session SET places=$z WHERE xtra_session.id=$id";
    $add = $modx->db->query($sql);
    $msg = ($add? "available places has been updated" : "error: ".mysql_error());
    }
    else {
    echo "Please enter a number of places to change"; 
    }
```

Thank you for your valued suggestions.